# query users by role

Tags: plugin-development, mysql, user-roles

I have a custom plugin which queries users and usermeta, but I now need to filter admins out of the results. A very simplified version of my sql query is:

```
SELECT * FROM usermeta LEFT JOIN users ON users.ID = user_id 
WHERE meta_key = 'last_name' AND 
user_role != 'admin' 
ORDER BY meta_value 
ASC LIMIT 0, 25
```

`user_role` is not a field, and i saw how it is stored as a config string, but i don't see how to make an equivalent query to this. Am i missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
// get users with specified roles
function getUsersWithRole( $roles ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( ! is_array( $roles ) )
        $roles = array_walk( explode( ",", $roles ), 'trim' );
    $sql = '
        SELECT  ID, display_name
        FROM        ' . $wpdb->users . ' INNER JOIN ' . $wpdb->usermeta . '
        ON          ' . $wpdb->users . '.ID             =       ' . $wpdb->usermeta . '.user_id
        WHERE       ' . $wpdb->usermeta . '.meta_key        =       \'' . $wpdb->prefix . 'capabilities\'
        AND     (
    ';
    $i = 1;
    foreach ( $roles as $role ) {
        $sql .= ' ' . $wpdb->usermeta . '.meta_value    LIKE    \'%"' . $role . '"%\' ';
        if ( $i < count( $roles ) ) $sql .= ' OR ';
        $i++;
    }
    $sql .= ' ) ';
    $sql .= ' ORDER BY display_name ';
    $userIDs = $wpdb->get_col( $sql );
    return $userIDs;
}
```

Comment: nice: D you can also do this using the WP_User_Search class from wp-admin/includes/user.php

Comment: As valid as your answer is, it highlights everything that's wrong in the WP RBAC.

Comment: Denis, I agree with you, WP RBAC is a pita :).  Thanks the answer though, it helped lead me down a good path.

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd line within the function did not work for me as `array_walk` returns a boolean instead of the desired array. I've changed line 3 to:

```
$roles = array_map('trim',explode( ",", $roles ));
```

And it works for me now.